# Compute missing box dimensions from given ones

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

Given the structure:

```
structure box_dimensions:
    int? left
    int? right
    int? top
    int? bottom
    point? top_left     
    point? top_right
    point? bottom_left
    point? bottom_right
    point? top_center
    point? bottom_center
    point? center_left
    point? center_right
    point? center
    int? width
    int? height
    rectangle? bounds
```

where each field can be defined or not.

How would you implement the function `check_and_complete(box_dimensions)` ?

- That function should return an error if there is not enough fields defined to describe a box, or too many.
- If input is consistent, it should compute the undefined fields.

You can describe a box by its center, width and height, or top_left and bottom_right corners, etc

The only solution I can think of contains way to many if-elses. I'm sure there's a smart way to do it.

**EDIT**

If you wonder how I end up with a structure like that, here is why :

I'm toying with the idea of a "layout by constraints" system:

User define a bunch of boxes, and for each box define a set of constraints like "box_a.top_left = box_b.bottom_right", "box_a.width = box_b.width / 2".

The real structure fields are actually expression AST, not values.

So I need to check if a box is "underconstrained" or "overconstrained", and if it's ok, create the missing expression AST from the given ones.

Comment: No, I think too many if-elses is exactly the way to solve this one. It's a badly redundant structure to begin with - what happens if you get input that's inconsistent with itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, certainly there will be too many `if-else`s.
Here's my attempt to keep them reasonably organized:

```
howManyLefts = 0

if (left is set) { realLeft = left; howManyLefts++; }
if (top_left is set) { realLeft = top_left.left; howManyLefts++; }
if (bottom_left is set) { realLeft = bottom_left.left; howManyLefts++; }
if (center_left is set) { realLeft = center_left.left; howManyLefts++; }
if (bounds is set) { realLeft = bounds.left; howManyLefts++; }

if (howManyLefts > 1) return error;
```

Now, repeat that code block for `center`, `right` and `width`.
Now you end up with `howManyLefts`, `howManyCenters`, `howManyRights` and `howManyWidths`, all of them being either zero or one, depending on whether the value was provided or not. You need **exactly** two values set and two unset, so:

```
if (howManyLefts + howManyRights + howManyCenters + howManyWidths != 2) return error

if (howManyWidths == 0)
{
  // howManyWidths is 0, so we look for the remaining 0 and assume the rest is 1s
  if (howManyCenters == 0)
    { realWidth = realRight - realLeft; realCenter = (realRight + realLeft) / 2; }
  else if (howManyLefts == 0)
    { realWidth = 2 * (realRight - realCenter); realLeft = realRight - realWidth; }
  else
    { realWidth = 2 * (realCenter - realLeft); realRight = realLeft + realWidth; }
}
else
{
  // howManyWidths is 1, so we look for the remaining 1 and assume the rest is 0s
  if (howManyCenters == 1)
    { realLeft = realCenter - realWidth / 2; realRight = realCenter + realWidth / 2; }
  else if (howManyLefts == 1)
    { realRight = realLeft + realWidth; realCenter = (realRight + realLeft) / 2; }
  else
    { realLeft = realRight - realWidth; realCenter = (realRight + realLeft) / 2; }
}
```

Now, repeat everything for the vertical axis (i.e. replacing { `left`, `center`, `right`, `width` } with { `top`, `center`, `bottom`, `height` }).

Comment: Hi Jojonete. I ended up doing something just like you explained : each axis needs exactly two constraints among (left/top, center/middle, right/bottom and width/height). Thanks for your answer !